# LINQ Merging results in rows

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, merge, grouping

I have a LINQ query which returns a set of rows. The structure is:

```
NAME,    col1, col2, col3, col4
name1     1    null  null  null
name1    null   1    null  null
name1    null  null   1     1
```

As a result I want to have one row containing

```
name1     1     1     1     1
```

So I want to group those results by name and merge (sum?) the other columns so if I have not null in one of the rows in a column - I will receive anything except null.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Do you *actually* want summation or not? What would you want the result to be if one of those null values was actually a 2?

Comment: you need to give better sample data to show how you want to group stuff etc.

Comment: As I mentioned in last phrase "anything except null" I need some kind of boolean true or false. In my case null would be false and anything else would be true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class MyObj
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Col1 { get; set; }
    public int? Col2 { get; set; }
    public int? Col3 { get; set; }
    public int? Col4 { get; set; }
}

List<MyObj> l = new List<MyObj> {
    new MyObj {Name = "name1", Col1 = 1 },
    new MyObj {Name = "name1", Col2 = 1 },
    new MyObj {Name = "name1", Col3 = 1 },
    new MyObj {Name = "name1", Col4 = 1 }
};

var qry = from o in l
          group o by o.Name into g
          select new
          {
              Name = g.Key,
              Col1 = g.Any(e => e.Col1.HasValue) ? (int?)1 : null,
              Col2 = g.Any(e => e.Col2.HasValue) ? (int?)1 : null,
              Col3 = g.Any(e => e.Col3.HasValue) ? (int?)1 : null,
              Col4 = g.Any(e => e.Col4.HasValue) ? (int?)1 : null
          };
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public class AggregateRows
{
    class AA { public string A, B, C, D;}

    public void DoIt()
    {
        List<AA> a = new List<AA>(  ) 
        {
            new AA { A="1", B=null, C=null, D=null},
            new AA { A=null, B="1", C=null, D=null},
            new AA { A=null, B=null, C="1", D=null},
            new AA { A=null, B=null, C=null, D="1"},
        };

        var result = a.Aggregate( ( a1, a2 ) => new AA { A = a1.A ?? a2.A, B = a1.B ?? a2.B, C = a1.C ?? a2.C, D = a1.D ?? a2.D } );
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}{3}",result.A,result.B,result.C,result.D);
    }
}
```

yields

```
1111
```

and

```
public class AggregateRows
{
    class AA
    {
        public string N, A, B, C, D;
    }

    public void DoIt()
    {
        List<AA> data = new List<AA>() 
        {
            new AA { N="Name", A="1", B=null, C=null, D=null},
            new AA { N="Name", A=null, B="2", C=null, D=null},
            new AA { N="Name", A=null, B=null, C="3", D=null},
            new AA { N="Name", A=null, B=null, C=null, D="4"},
            new AA { N="Name2", A="2", B=null, C=null, D=null},
            new AA { N="Name2", A=null, B="2", C=null, D=null},
            new AA { N="Name2", A=null, B=null, C="2", D=null},
            new AA { N="Name2", A=null, B=null, C=null, D="2"},
        };

        var results = data.GroupBy( a => a.N )
            .Select( k =>
            {
                var values = k.Aggregate( ( a1, a2 ) => new AA
                {
                    A = a1.A ?? a2.A,
                    B = a1.B ?? a2.B,
                    C = a1.C ?? a2.C,
                    D = a1.D ?? a2.D
                } );
                return new AA { N = k.Key, A = values.A, B = values.B, C = values.C, D = values.D };
            } );
        foreach ( var result in results )
            Console.WriteLine( "{0} {1}{2}{3}{4}", result.N, result.A, result.B, result.C, result.D );
    }
}
```

yields

```
Name 1234
Name2 2222
```

EDIT: In response to your clarification...

I guess you'll be able to take it from here then. If all you want to do is find out whether there is a column within the group, then the `Any` operator like in Bruno's answer is the way to go. `Aggregate` is only necessary if you're trying to actually visit all the values in order to do something more complex like summing them (although as Jon alluded to, `Sum` handles that specific case).

In short, what you want is grouping like in both the answer, and then within the group you either use `Aggregate` to merge row by row or multiple `Any` on the results of the `GroupBy` depending on which is clearer in your context (or more efficient if you have a large set of data within each group)

Comment: Sure you meant
Console.WriteLine( "{0} {1}{2}{3}{4}", result.N, result.A, result.B, result.C, result.D );

Comment: @melco-man: Yes, thanks - changed it (I actually had the right code elsewhere but was editing the changes into the post in parallel and the editor definitely doesnt help for doing that in long posts!)